# Server Hangup IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, wcf, iis

We have had reports from some users today of getting the error "Server Hangup".
They see a blank page with this error message at the top and underneath the message "Description: Server Hangup"

They see this error when using an ASP.NET MVC application at a particular screen that is calling a WCF web service on another server. The application is hosted in IIS 7.5.

Any ideas on how I can track down the source of this issue?

Comment: RDP to the server, call the site locally and read the detailed error report. Event Viewer is also a great way to start

Answer (score 0):

If you are suspicious about the code, you can try using this tools which is a Microsoft product, which I had also used and found the problems on my code and fixed it with this tool:

Debug Diagnostic Tool v1.2

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26798

Answer (score 0):

If the error is random (ie you can't duplicate it), I would look at event viewers on both the IIS server, as well as on the host of the WCF service.

Comment: You could make this answer more helpful be linking to relevant resources such as this one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524984(v=vs.90).aspx

Comment: Duly noted and appreciated!